# Calculating topic distribution of an unseen document on GenSim

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, lda

I am trying to use LDA module of GenSim to do the following task

"Train a LDA model with one big document and keep track of 10 latent topics. Given a new, unseen document, predict probability distribution of 10 latent topics".

As per tutorial here: http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut2.html, this seems possible for a document in a corpus, but I am wondering if it it would be possible for an unseen document.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation you posted it looks like you can train your model like this:

```
>>> model = models.LdaModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=100)
```

And then from [this page](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html) it looks like you can apply your model on "an unseen document" like this:

```
>>> doc_lda = model[doc_bow]
```

Where `doc_bow` is a bag-of-words generated by the [`doc2bow`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html#gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary.doc2bow) tool.

Comment: Could you explain what doc_lda is and how it can be analyzed?

Comment: doc_lda could also be called 'a' or 'b' it returns the topic allocation for doc_bow like this:  [(0, 0.33), (1, 0.33), (2, 0.33)] so the topic followed by the percentage that that comment/document/text data falls into that topic

Comment: How can I extract the topic name from above comment mentioned  . And if I have a text like text="The days  are bright and good" . And in my predefined lda model has 10 topics. Does it calculate topic probability of all the  words ?.  For now I assume text I mentioned is after stop word stemmin etc