# How to use gensim topic modeling to predict new document?

Tags: document, gensim, predict, lda

I am new to gensim topic modeling. Here is my sample code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
import re
from pprint import pprint
# Gensim
import gensim
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
from gensim.models import CoherenceModel
# spacy for lemmatization
import spacy
# Plotting tools
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim  # don't skip this
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline
# Enable logging for gensim - optional
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.ERROR)
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",category=DeprecationWarning)
# NLTK Stop words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
stop_words.extend(['from', 'subject', 're', 'edu', 'use'])
train=pd.DataFrame({'text':['find the most representative document for each topic',
                            'topic distribution across documents',
                            'to help with understanding the topic',
                            'one of the practical application of topic modeling is to determine']})
text=pd.DataFrame({'text':['how to find the optimal number of topics for topic modeling']})

data =  train.loc[:,'text'].values.tolist()

def sent_to_words(sentences):
    for sentence in sentences:
        yield(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(str(sentence), deacc=True))

data_words = list(sent_to_words(data))
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(data_words)
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in data_words]
lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus,
                                            id2word=id2word,
                                            num_topics=3)
```

So far so good. But I want to use lda_model to predict text. I at least need to know topic distribution over text and all the topic-word relation.

I think prediction is very common and important function for lda. But I do not know where I can find such function in gensim. Some answers says doc_lda = model[doc_bow] is prediction ([Calculating topic distribution of an unseen document on GenSim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40924185/calculating-topic-distribution-of-an-unseen-document-on-gensim)). But I am not sure about it.

Comment: Do you want to generate a document from the model? This can but done but I think it is the least useful thing to do as the LDA model would only produce a bag of words. But if you already had a few words and wanted to know what other words were likely to appear in a document with those words, I would find that interesting. I may have seen a paper where LDA was used in this regard to do ranking for autocomplete.

Comment: thanks. I want to predict what topics a new document might focus on using the trained lda model

Comment: I have again removed more please-help begging from your question. Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 
train=pd.DataFrame({'text':['find the most representative document for each topic',
                        'topic distribution across documents',
                        'to help with understanding the topic',
                        'one of the practical application of topic modeling is to determine']})
text=pd.DataFrame({'text':['how to find the optimal number of topics for topic modeling']})


def sent_to_words(sentences):
for sentence in sentences:
    yield(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(str(sentence), deacc=True))

#using your train data to train the model with 4 topics

data_words = list(sent_to_words(train['text']))
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(data_words)
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in data_words]

lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus,
                                        id2word=id2word,
                                        num_topics=4)

#  predicting new text which is in text dataframe  
new_text_corpus =  id2word.doc2bow(text['text'][0].split())
lda[new_text_corpus]

#op

Out[75]:
[(0, 0.5517368), (1, 0.38150477), (2, 0.032756805), (3, 0.03400166)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
new_doc=your processed text
new_doc_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(new_doc)
ldamodel.get_document_topics(new_doc_bow)
```